# Predicting in which medium will the oxidation occur

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

[image]

The image above contains the redox half-reaction for Mn2+ oxidation and their standard electrode potentials. The first two are in base medium and the second two are in acid medium. How can I predict in which medium the oxidation will actually take place? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm, it's a simple matter of comparing potentials. Why would you have any trouble here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schmidt, half cells don't have a full meaning. We cannot interpret their use without another half-cell. So in a table you see a lot manganese half cell, some of them are in basic medium and some of them are in acidic medium.

First of all your "other" half cell is missing. What do you wish to oxidize with manganese ions? From a practical perspective, the reducing substrate will decide what medium should be chosen.

It is your completely your *choice* to pick an acidic medium or alkaline medium. Let me give a practical example. If we wish to oxidize iron (II) ions to iron (III). Say, for experimental purposes, no precipitation or solids are required in the products. As a result one would choose an acidic medium to conducting this reaction.

However, if we somehow choose alkaline medium, we will form solid products such as MnO$_2$ or Mn(OH)$_2$.

Have you heard of Winkler's titration? It is used for determining the dissolved oxygen content in water with manganese (II) salt. Here we want a precipitate of Mn(OH)$_2$ to form, which can readily react with dissolved oxygen. So alkaline medium is used.

So the choice of alkaline or acidic medium for a redox reaction is totally up to you. The question of prediction does not arise.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To answer your first question, in my post I'm talking about $\ce{Mn^2+}$ oxidation with $\ce{O2}$

Comment: Right, so this is a perfect example of Winkler titration. In Winkler's titration, we want a Mn$^{2+}$ to precipitate as Mn(OH)$_2$. So we want a basic medium. This is immediately oxidized by dissolved oxygen. When we wish to have metallic precipitates as hydroxides or hydrated oxides, as products, basic medium is good for that.

Comment: I understand, but how can I prove, mathematically and thermodynamically wise, that the reaction is possible only in basic medium?

Comment: No you cannot- at least from scratch. There is some chemistry which is involved. You decide what products *you* want. Math or thermo won't tell you which products will be formed. May be you can do an exercise. Try to calculate the Ecell of oxidation of Mn(II) to Mn (IV) by oxygen gas  in acidic medium and in basic medium. I would choose the medium which shows higher (positive) Ecell. Find the appropriate half cells (not the ones listed in your question).

Comment: You would find them here in this book https://archive.org/details/oxidationstateso00lati

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $(2$) and ($3$) are two equivalent ways of writing one and the same equation. Let's start by writing the Nernst equation for your second equation, which I repeat here $$\ce{O_2 + 2H_2O + 4 e^- <=>  4 OH^-}$$
The corresponding Nernst equation is, without the units *Volt* : $$\ce{E = 0.40 - \frac{0.0592}{4} log[OH^-]^{4} = 0.40  - 0.0592 log[OH^-]}  $$ If $\ce{[OH^-]}$ is replaced by $\ce{\frac{10^{-14}}{[H^+]}}$, the equivalent following equation is obtained $$\ce{E = 0.40 - 0.0592 log \frac{10^{-14}}{[H+]} = 0.40 + 14·0.0592 + 0.0592 · log [H+] = 1.23 + 0.0592 log[H+] }$$ And this last formula is exactly the Nernst equation corresponding to your $3$rd formula, which I repeat here, just for fun $$\ce{O_2 + 4 H+ + 4 e^- <=> 2H_2O}$$

Comment: I understand what you explained and thanks, but how exactly does this answer my question?

Comment: @Schmitt. Do as you want. You may use your second or your third equation. It does not matter. With any of these you will get the same result. It is not the case for equation (1) and (4). In a basic medium you must use equation (1). In an acidic medium the hydroxydes do not exist as they are dissolved by H+ ions. So in an acidic medium, you must use the equation (4)

Comment: It seems to me that we don't understand eachother, and I'm sorry, it might be my bad. My initial question was not which equation corresponds to which medium, but in what medium will the oxidation of the Mn2+ ion is actually possible and how can I demonstrate that.

Comment: Agree, "how exactly does this answer my question? "

Answer (score -1):

OK, hand onto your seat, your electrochemical half cell reactions do not necessarily indicate anything about the underlying reaction mechanics.

You have to know the precise species involved to ascertain if they even exist at the specified pH, and, if existing, their solubility and decomposition pathway which can be pH-dependent relating to the medium.

Here is an example of the half cell reactions for the so-called Bleach Battery based on Aluminum metal corroding in acidified bleach containing HOCl and an inert electrode of copper.

At anode:

$\ce{Al -> Al^{3+} + 3 e-}$

$\ce{Al^{3+} + 3 OH- -> Al(OH)3 (s)}$

At the surface of the inert copper cathode:

$\ce{HOCl + e- -> .ClOH-}$

At pH < 5, the decompostion of the radical proceeds as follows:

$\ce{.ClOH- -> .Cl + OH-}$

$\ce{.Cl + .Cl -> Cl2 }$

and there is chlorine gas evolution.

Now, what happens in the alkaline bleach battery variation with Aluminum metal in NaOCl:

$\ce{NaOCl + H2O <=> Na+ + OH- + HOCl}$

So, largely the same except that now the formed radical behaves differently at pH >5 per the reaction:

$\ce{.ClOH- -> Cl- + .OH}$

So, no evolution of chlorine is apparent and just the precipitation of Al(OH)3

**[EDIT]** Interestingly, I did find this citation on the [acidic Bleach Battery half-cell reaction](http://www.exo.net/~pauld/saltwater/), to quote:

> (7) $\ce{HOCl + H+ + e- -> 1/2 Cl2 (g) + H2O Eo = 1.63 V}$

Note, this reaction would relate to the reaction mechanics of:

$\ce{H+ + e- <=> .H }$

$\ce{.H + HOCl <=> .Cl + H2O}$

$\ce{.Cl + .Cl <=> Cl2}$

which is an alternative possible path when H+ concentration is high and HOCl is low.

Further, in **alkaline** conditions, adding $\ce{OH-}$ to both sides of Equation (7), reduces to my general cited reaction as:

$\ce{HOCl (aq) + e- -> .ClOH- (aq)}$

Source: See [Supplement Table S1](http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/22/10/1684) and click on Supplement F1 to download.

Followed by:

$\ce{.ClOH- (aq) -> Cl- (aq) + .OH (aq)}$

as I previously cited.

Comment: At least Maurice was talking about OP's reaction...